# Box2dWeb dynamic vs static bodies restitution

Tags: javascript, box2d, box2dweb

I've got a Box2dWeb simulation with some dynamic bodies. I used the same fixture for all dynamic bodies like this:

```
var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
fixDef.density = 1.0;
fixDef.friction = 0.1;
fixDef.restitution = 0;
```

I thought restitution set to 0 would prevent any bouncing but when spawning a stack of dynamic bodies it acts like a spring. The example is [here](http://www.lelloman.altervista.org). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is not the restitution. the blocks are overlapping and trying to get out. you get something like tunneling. try to increase velocityIterations and positionIterations.